# Usar parâmetro que contém uma fórmula da data atual na origem dos dados

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Eu recebo arquivos de extração do banco de dados no formato .csv com o padrão:

> C://diretorio_pessoal/CSV_01-01-2019/arquivo.csv

Uma nova pasta é criada todo dia, então pra automatizar isso no power BI, na orgiem dos dados fiz o comando abaixo:

```
= Csv.Document(File.Contents(pCaminho & DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "\2_areas_tematicas.csv"),[Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=6, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
```

Gostaria de colocar todo esse comando de data em um parâmetro, assim como eu fiz com o diretório *pCaminho*, porém ele não aceita:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quem puder ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Acredito que seja por causa das aspas.

Comment: Breno, tirei/alterei as aspas. Não deu certo